# Specified cast is not valid - how to resolve this error?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created view in Oracle SQL and I need to view the data in an ASP.NET Core MVC view but when I run the view, I got an error

> Specified cast is not valid

This is the view script :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW TRNGKAASH.LAB_RESULT_VIEW
(
   HOSPITAL_NO,
   LAB_ORDER_NO,
   PATIENT_NAME_A,
   PATIENT_NAME_E,
   PATIENT_HOSPITAL,
   PATIENT_NO,
   EVENT_NO,
   PATIENT_CATEGORY,
   PRIO_FLAG,
   PATIENT_SOURCE_IND,
   SERV_REQUEST_DATE_G,
   SERV_REQUEST_DATE_H,
   SERV_REQUEST_USER_ID,
   SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NO,
   SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NAME,
   INIT_DIAGNISIS,
   LAB_NO,
   MEDICAL_CHECK,
   SAMPLE_NO,
   SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_G,
   SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_H,
   SAMPLE_COLLECTED_BY,
   SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_G,
   SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_H,
   SAMPLE_RECIEVED_BY,
   SERV_TYPE,
   SERV_NO,
   GROUP_NO,
   END_RESULT,
   CANCEL_DATE_G,
   CANCEL_DATE_H,
   CANCEL_REASON,
   CANCEL_BY,
   SAMPLE_NOTE,
   PROVIDING_RESOURCE,
   HEPARIN_FLAG
)
   BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS
   SELECT H.HOSPITAL_NO,
          H.LAB_ORDER_NO,
          H.PATIENT_NAME_A,
          H.PATIENT_NAME_E,
          H.PATIENT_HOSPITAL,
          H.PATIENT_NO,
          H.EVENT_NO,
          H.PATIENT_CATEGORY,
          H.PRIO_FLAG,
          H.PATIENT_SOURCE_IND,
          H.SERV_REQUEST_DATE_G,
          H.SERV_REQUEST_DATE_H,
          H.SERV_REQUEST_USER_ID,
          H.SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NO,
          H.SERV_REQUEST_DOCTOR_NAME,
          H.INIT_DIAGNISIS,
          H.LAB_NO,
          H.MEDICAL_CHECK,
          S.SAMPLE_NO,
          S.SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_G,
          S.SAMPLE_COLLECTED_DATE_H,
          S.SAMPLE_COLLECTED_BY,
          S.SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_G,
          S.SAMPLE_RECEIVED_DATE_H,
          S.SAMPLE_RECIEVED_BY,
          S.SERV_TYPE,
          S.SERV_NO,
          S.GROUP_NO,
          S.END_RESULT,
          S.CANCEL_DATE_G,
          S.CANCEL_DATE_H,
          S.CANCEL_REASON,
          S.CANCEL_BY,
          S.SAMPLE_NOTE,
          S.PROVIDING_RESOURCE,
          S.HEPARIN_FLAG
     FROM LAB_ORDERS_STS H, LAB_SAMPLE_STS S
    WHERE     H.HOSPITAL_NO = S.HOSPITAL_NO
          AND H.LAB_ORDER_NO = S.LAB_ORDER_NO
          AND H.END_RESULT <> 1;
```

This is the model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OracleHIS.Models
{
    public partial class LabResultView
    {
        public string HospitalNo { get; set; } = null!;
        public long LabOrderNo { get; set; }
        public string? PatientNameA { get; set; }
        public string? PatientNameE { get; set; }
        public string? PatientHospital { get; set; }
        public long? PatientNo { get; set; }
        public byte? EventNo { get; set; }
        public int? PatientCategory { get; set; }
        public int? PrioFlag { get; set; }
        public int? PatientSourceInd { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ServRequestDateG { get; set; }
        public string? ServRequestDateH { get; set; }
        public string? ServRequestUserId { get; set; }
        public short? ServRequestDoctorNo { get; set; }
        public string? ServRequestDoctorName { get; set; }
        public string? InitDiagnisis { get; set; }
        public int? LabNo { get; set; }
        public bool? MedicalCheck { get; set; }
        public long SampleNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SampleCollectedDateG { get; set; }
        public string? SampleCollectedDateH { get; set; }
        public short? SampleCollectedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? SampleReceivedDateG { get; set; }
        public string? SampleReceivedDateH { get; set; }
        public string? SampleRecievedBy { get; set; }
        public int? ServType { get; set; }
        public int? ServNo { get; set; }
        public int? GroupNo { get; set; }
        public int? EndResult { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CancelDateG { get; set; }
        public string? CancelDateH { get; set; }
        public int? CancelReason { get; set; }
        public string? CancelBy { get; set; }
        public string? SampleNote { get; set; }
        public int ProvidingResource { get; set; }
        public bool? HeparinFlag { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

This is the `Index` controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var results = labResultsView.List(); 
    return View();
}
```

and the repository code :

```
public IList<LabResultView> List()
{
    return db.LabResultViews.ToList();
}
```

The error appears in the repository code on this line :

```
   return db.LabResultViews.ToList();
```

This is the screenshot showing the error:

[image]

Please let me know how to solve this error.

These are the tables data types :

LAB_ORDERS_STS table :

[image]

LAB_SAMPLE_STS table :

[image]

Comment: @RuikaiFeng ok I will check

Comment: To resolve the error its important to check your `database data type` could you please include that the question?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron sure I updated the question and added the tables columns and data types .

Comment: Chnage `byte? EventNo` to `long` or relevant data type, of course number doesn't matched with `byte`, I am continue checking

Comment: `MedicalCheck` set has number in database, however, `number` doesn't correspond with `bool` I guess,  it should be set as `int` if it contains `0` or `1`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron ok I will change it and inform you thank you so much

Comment: Sure, meanwhile, I am checking if anything else found.

Comment: Hello, was the issue resolved? Have you tired the solution provided? Please let me know if any further assistance required on this.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron hello yes solved thank you so much i will inform you if there is any issue :)

Comment: You are welcome and Glad to know that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specified cast is not valid

Based on the error, I think following `data types` are inconsistent

`byte? EventNo` should be `long`,

`short? SampleCollectedBy`  should be `int`

`bool? MedicalCheck` should be changed to `int` if it contains number like `0` or `1` other than `oracle number` should be deal with `decimal`

`short? SampleCollectedBy` better to change to `int`

`bool? HeparinFlag` also need to replace in `int` if it only contains `0` or `1` if contains other then `decimal`

**Note:** So far investigated on your shared `POCO Class` and `data entity model` based on the error your issue mostly related to defination of `asp.net core POCO` class which doesn't matached with the `database entity defination`. You could follow this official Chart for reference:

[image]

[image]

More details can be founded at [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-data-type-mappings)